# Get rid of forward slash in link

Tags: regex, hyperlink

I'm parsing remote sites. They contain keywords which are being replaced with the correct values. My problem arises when I want to parse links, like so:

```
<a href="{_SOMEKEYWORD_}">somestupidtext</a>
```

SOMEKEYWORD contains an url (i.e. http://www.stackoverflow.com) but there is always a forward slash occurring, like so:

```
<a href="/{_SOMEKEYWORD_}">somestupidtext</a>
```

This obviously breaks all the links. I thought of a regex but am very open to better(?) solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You might also be able to get away with a simple string replace if the slash is the only thing you want to remove and it always occurs immediately after the `href`:

C#:

```
string url = "<a href=\"/{_SOMEKEYWORD_}\">somestupidtext</a>";
url = String.Replace("href=\"/", "href=\"");
```

Comment: True, but I came to the solutions immediately after questioning (as always, I suppose...). I ended up using this (just made the slash optional).
preg_replace("/\/?{_(.*?)_}/ime", "\$data['$1']",$html);